# How to mount a chartjs component using http call?

Tags: reactjs, graph, axios

I am working with react and using react-chartjs to mount a graph from a JSON information. I am able to get data from JSON online and sort it to the data that is needed using the map method. But the data i need from the componentDidMount() is not getting passed to the render method. I tried console.log to check the data at different stages.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
 import axios from "axios";

 const headingStyle = {
 "text-align": "center"
 };





 class DoughnutExample extends Component {
 state = {}
 async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({users: [ ]})
    const { data: users } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bw0u4"
    );
    this.setState({ users: users.map(({ chart }) => chart) });
    console.log( users)
  }
 render() {
  console.log(this.state.users)

  return (
  <div className="card card-1" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
    <h3 style={headingStyle}>Cash Flow</h3>
    <Doughnut data={this.state.users} />

   </div>
  );
  }
  }

  export default DoughnutExample;
```

My JSON file : http://myjson.com/bw0u4

Answer (score 0):

`users` needs to be initialized as initial state:

```
state = {
    users: {}
}
```

And given the [provided data structure](http://myjson.com/bw0u4) and [the expected data structure](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure) for Doughnut chart type, `data` prop could be initialized like this:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(
  "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bw0u4"
);

const users = {
    datasets : [{
        data : data.map(({chart}) => chart)
    }]
}
this.setState({ users });
```

where

```
<Doughnut data={this.state.users} />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4hdvd2)